# Is this Analytic functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Why is the function not analytic in the complex plane? I believe it is analytic on real plane.

$e^{(-\frac{1}{z^2})}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Well a complex function should be infinitely differentiable and should converge. this happens on real plane. But what happens in complex plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function looks pretty well behaved on the real line (not plane!), however, already here you see some pecularities. E.g. it's infinitely differentiable at $x=0$, however, the Taylor series at that point has zero radius of convergence. The reason becomes obvious if you look at the function in the complex plane. Try approaching zero from other directions than on the real line, e.g. from $\pm i$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** A function is analytic if and only if its Taylor series about $x_0$ converges to the function in some neighborhood for every $x_0$ in its domain.